# Can I use ironruby that different from other implementation of ruby?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio

I am taking a ruby class this semester. In my book it said that there is an implementation of ruby for VS called **IronRuby**. I'd like to use visual studio that I use any way for work. My only concern is to know if there's significant difference (if any) with the other rubies so that I can go ahead and Use VS2012? In class we use a book called "**Ruby Programming Language by Matsumoto**"

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just doing the exercises in the book, you should be fine.

Personally, I would not use it because:

- IronRuby hasn't had a stable (or alpha) release in years, and its future is uncertain (little project activity and missing lead developers).
- It's [not 100% compatible](http://www.ironruby.info/) with MRI, so you may run into weirdness, though I haven't been able to find a more detailed RubySpec.
- More Ruby is written and tested on Unix-like machines than Windows, so if you need to use gems, you may run into weird issues with IronRuby that don't occur in MRI.
- You should spend most of your time learning in `irb`, so Visual Studio doesn't really help you :). (`irb` is the interactive prompt -- you can test your code in real-time, instead of having to save and run [or compile].)

Comment: By the way, I am trying to download the Ruby Installer but I can access the page because of an history about Forge mirror. Here's the link. http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. I'm really stuck. Is there any other solution for a windows-lap top owner like me? Can I use some thing else that RubyInstaller that I cannot get anyway?

Comment: @Richard77: Weird. Try going to `http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/76054/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p194.exe/noredirect` ([clickable URL](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/76054/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p194.exe/noredirect)). That worked for me -- not sure why it doesn't work normally.

Comment: I thank you very much as I spent to much time just to get it installed. In less than a minute, I do have it installed. Thanks

Comment: @Richard77: No problem -- have fun with Ruby! If you want to play around in IRB, just start typing and hit `TAB` to complete a method (e.g., 'foo'.cap<TAB>). It's a great way to discover methods outside of skimming the docs.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind as at the first glance, ruby is really quite different from C# or even Javascript.